# Taking decltype of main

Tags: c++11, program-entry-point, decltype

Trying to invoke `hi` or `std::move` on it results in this:

```
/tmp/cch3DRvH.o: In function `main':

main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5): undefined reference to `hi(int, char**)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    decltype(main) hi;
    decltype(main) hi2;
    // std::function<int(int, char**)> hi2 = std::move(hi);
    // hi(argc, argv);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(main), decltype(hi)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_function<decltype(main)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_function<decltype(hi)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(std::move(main)), decltype(std::move(hi))>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(hi2), decltype(hi)>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:16:54: warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function ‘::main’ [-Wpedantic]
     std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(std::move(main)), decltype(std::move(hi))>::value << std::endl;
main.cpp:16:54: warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function ‘::main’ [-Wpedantic]
true
true
true
true
true
```

It seems `hi` is almost the same as `main` except it doesn't give warnings like when using `std::cout << hi`. Is it possible to get this program to not output `undefined reference to`hi(int, char**)'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype(main)` is an alias for the type `int(int, char **)`. You have declared a function `hi` with this type but did not define it.

To get rid of the `undefined reference` error, just define the function:

```
int hi( int, char ** ) {
    return 0;
}
```

The messages that appear before `true` are not output from your program but from the compiler.

Comment: Although that's true, to the best of my knowledge the OP doesn't need the definition. All the use cases listed just require a declaration.

Comment: @templatetypedef He asked "Is it possible to get this program to not output undefined reference tohi(int, char**)?" which must be in reference to another program, not shown.

Comment: Hm, I see. The whole `extern` stuff was confusing me. Makes sense.

Comment: @remyabel `extern` is the default; it doesn't matter if you leave it off a function declaration/definition or add it.